# How to load assembly from stream in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am experiencing with Roslyn on a .NET Core console application. I tried to create an assembly and compile it into a memory stream. But loading it seems to be missing an API ([that normally works on the regular .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
         syntaxTrees: new[] { pocoTree }, references: new[] { mscorlib, currentAssembly });

var ms = new MemoryStream();
var emitResult = compilation.Emit(ms);

var ourAssembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray()); // Fails to compile here
```

I get this error:

> cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'System.Reflection.AssemblyName'

What is the alternative in .NET Core to load from a steam? (other than physically saving the assembly and loading it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can load the assembly from a stream in .NET core using `AssemblyLoadContext`:

```
// requires "System.Runtime.Loader": "4.0.0",
protected virtual Assembly LoadAssembly(MemoryStream peStream, MemoryStream pdbStream)
{
    return System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(peStream, pdbStream);
}
```